# What kind of owner and group for these below list of files?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, rhel

what is the owner and group of this below file? It has 0 and 0 for owner and group.

```
-rw-rw-rw-   1 0        0             464 Oct 16 14:31 a.txt
```

I found those permissions after connecting to a remote server for which we does not have write permissions.

How to replicate the same permisions in my development machine?

Comment: `UID == 0` and `GID == 0` are `root`. As root `chmod 0666 filename && chown root:root filename`

Comment: i.e. no other user (other than root) can be able to rename that file right?

Comment: Right. The only way to alter it is either logged in as `root` or logged in as you and `su` to `root` or call the `chmod` and `chown` with `sudo`. (which is just `su` do..) Also, if you get rid of the `-n` option to your `ls` command and just use `ls -al /path/to/whatever` you will see the `user` and `group` names instead of the numbers.

Comment: I tried that, I did sudo to become the root and then ran 'chmod 0666 filename' and also 'chown root:root filename'. Now, after that, I logged in as myself, but I am able to rename that file, which i am not expecting, why I am able to rename even after setting the restricted permissions?

Comment: Well, of course you can, and I apologize, `-rw-rw-rw-` means the file is `'-'` not a directory (otherwise `'d'` would be first), both `'r'` readable and `'w'` writable ( `rw-`) by its owner (`root`), `rw-` by any member of the `root` group AND `rw-` by (world) anyone. Meaning any user can read and write the file and change its name or permissions -- BUT only `root` or members of the `root` group can change the user or group ownership TO `root`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0:0 is almost always root:root owner and group. The command, `cat /etc/group` shows group ID numbers. In most (all?) cases, users and groups with the same name share the same ID number.

Comment: Do I need to run "chown 0:0 a.txt" to repliacate that permission in my dev server?

Comment: Since it's a text file, you can set permissions to anything you want without problems. Unless it's required by some program, and it expects owner to be root (unlikely), you can change it to be owned by the desktop user (you) or leave it alone.